# Scrolling/loading issues Google Chrome/Opera

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, background-image, opera

I've been working on my website and it works flawlessly in Firefox and Safari (also no scrolling issues with IE), but it's opened in both Opera and Chrome the site keeps reloading every area every time you scroll a little bit so when you've loaded an area, you scroll to a new one (which loads strangely) and back again to the first location it reloads everything again. I found that the problems come from the background that I use, but once again, in half of the browsers it works flawlessly. Does anybody know how to get this code to work? I've tried changing the absolute attachment property to both fixed and relative but fixed only makes the site work more terrible and relative does the same as absolute.

Or... is it possible to add css specific for Firefox, IE and Safari to make sure it works there and delete the background image in the other browsers?

```
.div-1{
    background: url(../images/blue1.png), url(../images/background.jpg);
    background-attachment: absolute, absolute;
    background-position: left bottom, right top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-size: cover, cover;
    background-color:#000;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding:  10% 10% 30% 10%;
    border-bottom: 5px #000;
}

.div-2{
    background: url(../images/blue1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: absolute;
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-color:#000;
    color: #95C8D1;
    text-align: center;
    padding:  10% 10% 30% 10%;
    border-bottom: 5px #95C8D1;
    margin-top: -2px;
}

.div-3{
    background: url(../images/black1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: absolute;
    background-position: right bottom;
    background-color:#95C8D1;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding:  10% 10% 30% 10%;
    border-bottom: 5px #000;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

It's about the site: http://cdmolenaar.nl/en/

Answer (score 0):

The main problem you're facing is that your page (images, video) is massive (24MB). Chrome is redrawing the images when they enter the viewable area. I'd recommend:

1. I see you are loading a bunch of images that are not visible on the page.
2. None of your images are optimized/resized. When saving your images, try not to make them so much larger than they appear in the page.
3. The angled color pngs could probably be achieved with CSS or SVG. (Take a look at: http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/)

I can't tell you why Firefox and Safari are so much better (except they render differently). The images aren't technically reloading, but they do need to be decoded and painted to the page on scroll. Some general info about scroll Jank can be found here: http://jankfree.org/

Comment: Thank you so much! Will resize everything asap and hopefully that'll make it work better. Will see which other jankfree things I can apply aswell. Thank you! Would never have thought about resizing it all. Thank you!